# Trying to perform realtime emotion analysis in deepface library

Tags: python, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to use the 'analyze' function of the deepface library. This is all the code that I am running:

from deepface import DeepFace

DeepFace.analyze("known_faces")

But I end up getting this error :

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kn8aL.png)

I have 1.8 GB free in my C drive.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is not related to the free space in your disk. It tries to download pre-trained weights from google drive source. It seems that google drive download limit reached by the other users of deepface.

1- Try to download the pre-trained weight manually: https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1wUXRVlbsni2FN9-jkS_f4UTUrm1bRLyk

2- Copy it to the HOME/.deepface/weights folder.

Your home folder is like C:\Users\John